# What is the best way to Paginate Forge/BIM360 Docs files lists?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am currently in the process of implementing pagination, sort and search functionalities in the project files/plans/sheets views of BIM 360 Docs integration.

Since I couldn't find any best practices regarding to these features, I thought I would reach out so that I don't keep stuck reinventing the wheel.

**Background:**

Most of the implementation uses https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/ SDK.

Based on what I saw, pagination in Autodesk API is very basic and does not play well with filtered views. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like there is no way to get number of items in the view and/or calculate total number of pages in the resultset.

If one uses filtering to limit types of items returned by the API (e.g. documents, sheets, project files), API applies pagination first and filters second. That causes holes in returned resultsets, e.g. one would request page 1 sized as 5 items, and get 3 items back, then request similarly sized page 2 and get no items back, then page 3 would yield 2 items.

The above mentioned issues force us to use dynamic lazy-loading paging, similar to how it's currently done in the BIM360 Docs UI.

**Question:**

Is there a different, better way to paginate? Or do we have to lazy-load results while scrolling, never knowing how much records the next page would return?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, paginating is not available for Forge MD API of BIM360 currently as I know. Apologizing for any inconvenience caused.

However, it's been logged as request id `FDM-1769` a few days ago. I saw your name on the request list. So I think it will be supported in the future. Besides, a workaround is to fetch all data from the API, then paginate on the client side via Javascript.